# Prestashop 1.7. How to change cookie key?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need to change cookie key. It was in config/settings.inc.php in Prestashop 1.6.

settings.inc.php is deprecated in Prestashop 1.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the new settings file under `app/config/parameters.php`. There you can change the `secret` variable.

Comment: Hi! We try copy the cookie_key of PS 1.6 to the secret variable in PS 1.7, but this doesn't work, how did you do?